# How to remove words other than Stopwords from countvectorizer

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp

I want to retain only the words which I pass as Stopwords to the  countvectorizer.

```
CV= CountVectorizer(max_features=500,stop_words= frozenset(["word1", "word2","word3"]))
```

How to do this.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you want to use [`vocabulary` parameter](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) instead of `stop_words`:

```
CV = CountVectorizer(max_features=500, vocabulary=["word1","word2","word3"])
```